# Busqueda de datos de un array sobre dos arrays

Tags: javascript, array

Estoy realizando un codigo para intentar convertir unos datos en tabla.

En concreto tengo los datos en 3 arrays con la siguiente forma :

- Encuesta [**edad**,
  **nombre_del_periodico**]
- Intervalo
  [**Primer_numero_del_intervalo**(el numero
  menor),
     **Segundo_numero_del_intervalo** (el numero mayor)]
- Periodicos[**nombre_del_periodico**]

Me es necesario obtener las posiciones que ocupan los valores del array encuestas respecto a los otros dos arrays intentando hacerlo eficiente.Pongo un ejemplo:

[21,"el_pais"] ---> [3,0]

Ya que 21 estaria comprendido en el 4 intervalo [17,25] y 0 porque es el primer periodico ["el_pais"].

Pues bien , en principio recorro el array de encuestas y por cada encuesta comparo en el array de intervalos y periodicos sus posiciones , pero me es imposible no consigo que lo realice para todas las encuestas .

¿Alguna idea?
Muchas gracias.

```js
 var valores_encuesta = [[11, "el_pais"],[21,"el_pais"],[31,"el_mundo"],[42, "abc"],[45,"el_pais"],[46, "el_pais"],[50, "abc"],[51, "el_mundo"],[52,"el_mundo"],[70,"abc"],];
  
   var intervalos = [[1, 5],[6, 10],[11, 16],[17, 25],[26, 31],[32, 46],[47, 54],[55, 65],[66, 80],[81, 99],];
  
  var periodicos = ["el_pais","el_mundo","abc"];

  
  var x=0;
 var y=0;
  // Recorro el array con las encuestas para compararlos con los intervalos y los periodicos
 for (i=0 ;i<valores_encuesta.length-1;i++){ 
 
 console.log("------------------------------------------------------------------");
  
  //Recorro el array de los intervalos y me quedo con que posicion ocupa X
 while (x<intervalos.length-1 &&  
 !(intervalos[x][0]>=valores_encuesta[i][0] 
   && valores_encuesta[i][0]<=intervalos[x][1])){ 
 
   console.log("Encuesta: "+i+" Longitud :"+x+"Comparando "+intervalos[x][0]+">="+valores_encuesta[i][0]+"<="+intervalos[x][1]);
   x++;
  }

//Recorro el array de los periodicos y me quedo con la posicion y
 while (y<periodicos.length-1 &&
   valores_encuesta[i][1].localeCompare(periodicos[y])!=0
   ){//Recorro el array de los periodicos y me quedo con la posicion y
  y++;
 }
  
  console.log("Encuesta "+i+" con x["+x+"] y ["+y+"]"); 
  x=0;
  y=0;
 }
```

Comment: Se pueden cambiar los intervalos de array de dos dimensiones a uno simple? `intervalos = [5,10,16,25..];`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Aquí tienes la solucion, he utilizado dos `foreach`, el `indexOf` para conseguir el indice del periódico y al final concatenar el resultado como en tu pregunta.

```js
var valores_encuesta = [
    [11, "el_pais"],
    [21, "el_pais"],
    [31, "el_mundo"],
    [42, "abc"],
    [45, "el_pais"],
    [46, "el_pais"],
    [50, "abc"],
    [51, "el_mundo"],
    [52, "el_mundo"],
    [70, "abc"],
];

var intervalos = [
    [1, 5],
    [6, 10],
    [11, 16],
    [17, 25],
    [26, 31],
    [32, 46],
    [47, 54],
    [55, 65],
    [66, 80],
    [81, 99],
];

var periodicos = ["el_pais", "el_mundo", "abc"];

valores_encuesta.forEach(e => {
    var cont = 0;
    intervalos.forEach(i => {
        cont++;
        if (e[0] >= i[0] && e[0] <= i[1]) {
            
            var indexPeriodico = periodicos.indexOf(e[1]);

            console.log(e + ' ---> [' + cont+ ',' + indexPeriodico + "]" )
        }
    });
});
```